# Pickling inner classes

Tags: python, pickle

I have a python module called `model` with basically the following content:

```
class Database:

    class Publiation(object):
        pass

    class Article(Publication):
        pass

    class Book(Publication):
        pass

class AnotherDatabase:

    class Seminar(object):
        pass

    ...
```

I define the objects in the database as classes nested under a main class in order to organize them more distinctively. The objects are parsed from a large XML file, which takes time. I would like to pickle the imported objects to make them loadable in shorter time.

I get the error:

> pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle
>   : it's
>   not found as project.model.Article

The class is now `project.model.Article`, not `project.model.Database.Article` as defined. Can I fix this error and keep the classes nested like above? Is it a bad idea to organize classes by nesting them?

Comment: Yea nesting anything is bad.  If you don't "need" to have the parent/child relationship then you don't want to do it.  You do not want to create a sudoku puzzle for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly a lot simpler to keep your classes unnested. As an alternative, you can use packages to group the classes together.

In any case, there is an alternate serializer named [`cerealizer`](http://home.gna.org/oomadness/en/cerealizer/index.html) which I think could handle the nested classes. You would need to register the classes with it before deserialization. I've used it before when `pickle` wouldn't suffice (also problems related to the classes) and it works well!

Answer (score 5):

When an inner class is created, there is no way for the interpreter to know which class it was defined inside of, this information is not recorded. This is why pickle does not know where to look for the class Article.

Because of this there are numerous issues when using inner classes, not just when it comes to pickling. If there are classes at the module scope with the same name, it introduces a lot of ambiguity as there is no easy way to tell the two types apart (e.g. with repr or when debugging.)

As a result it is generally best to avoid nested classes in Python unless you have a very good reason for doing so.